# Spring-WS and Spring-integration: Getting SAXParseException: smartLifeCycleAttributeGroup

Tags: spring-integration, spring-ws

I am trying to implement a web service proxy following the steps from here.
http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/integration/114641-how-to-implement-the-web-service-proxy-pattern

Spring-ws-config.xml:

```
<int-ws:inbound-gateway id="proxy" request-channel="toOutbound"/>

<int:channel id="toOutbound" />

<int-ws:outbound-gateway id="out" request-channel="toOutbound" uri="http://localhost:8080/helloproxy" />
```

Getting this exception while deploying the proxy service.

> org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/ws/spring-integration-ws.xsd; lineNumber: 274; columnNumber: 72; src-
>   resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'integration:smartLifeCycleAttributeGroup' to a
>   (n) 'attribute group' component.

Can someone please help me fix this ? Is there something else to be added in the spring-ws-config xml ?

Thanks,
Sri

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or you have a mixing of spring-integration jar versions (SI-ws is of one version, but SI-core is of another), or it is just an issue of your IDE.

The Spring Nature (STS) should help to resolve all XSD validation issues.

Comment: Thank you.  Had missed out spring-integration-core. Adding the latest version helped solving this.